# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in C:\wamp\www\corporation\new_subject.php on line 29

Tags: php

I am getting error with the for loop and error name i have put it at the title of question please help me ...

```
<p>POSITION 
    <select name="postion">
        <?php
            $all_subj =  get_all_subjects();
            $subj_count     = mysql_num_rows($all_subj);

            for($count=1; $count < = $subj_count+1; $count++){
                echo " <option value='$count'>{$count}</option>" ;  
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Indrajeet Devre  it's your responsibility to check answers and mark one answer which is most suitable to you. It will help future visitors to find out solution easily.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just remove spaces between `<` and `=` like below:-

```
for($count=1; $count <= $subj_count+1; $count++){
```

Answer (score 1):

`< =` should come as  `<=`in `for` loops

```
<p>POSITION <select name="postion" >
        <?php
            $all_subj =  get_all_subjects();
            $subj_count     = mysql_num_rows($all_subj);

            for($count=1; $count <= $subj_count+1; $count++)
            {
                echo " <option value='$count'>{$count}</option>" ;
            }
        ?>

    </select>
</p>
```